# Is melting of Tar for road construction a reversible change?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, everyday-chemistry

In India roads are made up of a black liquid which is prepared by melting a black material(probably coal tar). After cooling the liquid becomes very rigid. Can this solid be converted back to its previous liquid state by heating?

P.S: This is a question in my book. I think that after getting solidified the chemical composition of Tar may change so it can't be converted back to its original state.

Comment: Chip off a little piece and try heating it. Chemistry is an experimental science. I think it would melt just fine.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I don't have proper apparatus. Heating Tar on a cooking stove would be very risky, I guess.

Comment: On extremely hot days I have observed this tar melt slightly. Whether it changes to the original material, I do not know.

Comment: If you've even seen a roof being tarred the tar is solid which is melted and then applied to the roof.

Answer (score 4):

Tar
 is mainly made up of a collection of very heavy hydrocarbons, with 
rather high melting temperatures. Commonly, it is mixed with some stones
 or gravel to make a harder surface for roads. It is possible to heat 
this up to soften or melt this; you can try it yourself by heating it in
 a metal can over a stove (don't use a container that you plan to keep 
clean) or in a wood or (char)coal fire.

EDIT: As MaxW pointed out, it would be a bad idea to do this inside the house because it would create a strong smell, similar to that created by whatever machine they used to make the road.

Comment: I wouldn't heat it indoors because it will stink up the house.

Comment: So it means melting solid tar doesn't change it's chemical composition?

Comment: @user31782 It depends on what other impurities are present in the tar. Pure tar will not change, but road tar might. I do not know what impurities are in it. Of course, you could always try melting some (outdoors) and letting it cool, and observe any differences.

Answer (score 3):

The process is reversible, and can actually happen to some extent in hot weather, [see here](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2012/07/wait-tarmac-can-melt/259565/) or [here](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-23315384).  It can definitely soften on a hot day, and it melts at $150\rm~^\circ C$.